# Swift Package Manager Files In Alphabetical Order?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I'm working on removing code from a project file and making it it's own standalone Swift Package. In doing so, I imported a bunch of files, and these files are now in alphabetical order.

Is there anyway to change this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Xcode? Are you viewing the code by opening the `Package.swift` file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A package consists of Swift source files and a manifest file. The manifest file, called **Package.swift**. Xcode uses Package.swift file to open Swift Package Manager **packages**. A package is not a project and has not had a project/workspace file like **.xcodeproj** or  **.xcworkspace**.

By convention, a target includes any source files located in the Sources/ directory. Just because has no project or workspace file it has no rules like alphabetical order or such so.

### Try this

Open Finder, add any source file on the disk system via copy to the package's sources directory. The file Immediately will appear on the (Xcode) package too.

#### Short Answer

For now, this is not possible. Who knows in the future releases. Personally, I didn't care a lot until I add an Objective-C project. Then I realize that it's super hard to organize things. I understand your point.

I hope this explains the situation.

Best

Comment: Thank you. I'll see about reorganizing for now by using folders or something with different names. Or maybe prefixing them with numbers

Comment: You're welcome. Kindly, I would prefer the directory solution. Best.